# Error in as.Date.numeric() : 'origin' must be supplied

Tags: r, date

I have received a paper in which they included the R files for their empirical results. Nevertheless, I have some problems while trying to run their codes:

```
data <- vni$R[198:length(vni$R)]; date <- vni$Date[198:length(vni$R)]
l <- length(data)
rw_length <- 52 # 52 weeks (~ 1 year)
bound <- vector()
avr <- vector()
for (i in (rw_length+1):l) {
  AVR.test <- AutoBoot.test(data[(i-rw_length):i],nboot=2000,"Normal",c(0.025, 0.975))
  bound <- append(bound, AVR.test$CI.stat)
  avr <- append(avr, AVR.test$test.stat)
}
lower <- bound[seq(1, length(bound), 2)]
upper <- bound[seq(2, length(bound), 2)]

results <- matrix(c(date[(rw_length+1):l],data[(rw_length+1):l],avr,upper, lower),ncol=5, dimnames = list(c(),c("Date", "Return", "AVR",  "Upper", "Lower")))
```

And I get the following error: `

> Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied`

for the `results <- matrix(c(date[(rw_length+1):l],data[(rw_length+1):l],avr,upper, lower),ncol=5, dimnames = list(c(),c("Date", "Return", "AVR",  "Upper", "Lower")))`

My dataset is:

```
          Date       P             R
1   2001-03-23  259.60  0.0000000000
2   2001-03-30  269.30  0.0366840150
3   2001-04-06  284.69  0.0555748690
4   2001-04-13  300.36  0.0535808860
5   2001-04-20  317.76  0.0563146260
...
935 2019-02-15  950.89  0.0454163960
936 2019-02-22  988.91  0.0392049380
937 2019-03-01  979.63 -0.0094283770
```

Could you please help me with that issue?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in a `matrix` must be the same class. This is often found when there's a string among numbers, where

```r
m <- matrix(0, nr=2, nc=2)
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0
m[1] <- "a"
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "0" 
# [2,] "0"  "0"
```

In this case, you have `Date` (first column) and `numeric` (all others? no idea what `AutoBoot` is). And because it's trying to coerce from least-complex to most-complex (from `numeric` to `Date`), the non-`Date` objects are being converted.

```r
matrix(c(Sys.Date(), 1.1))
# Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I suggest that trying to store this in a `matrix` is therefore fundamentally flawed. If you want to store a `Date` object among numbers, you have two options:

1. Store it as a `data.frame`, where each column can have its own class.
2. Pre-convert the `"Date"` data to `numeric` and store it as a number. This means that if/when you need the dates to be of class `Date` again, you'll need to `as.Date(..., origin="1970-01-01")`.

Comment: I find it interesting that `as.Date(1.1)` by itself works without error or complaint ...

Comment: I have convert date to numeric as you said `date <- as.numeric(date)` and it works!!!
Thank you so much !!!